# Script fails on spaces should I write sed to escape paths or change script to work on dirs

Tags: regex, linux, bash, parsing

I have a samba share of dirs (~1500) example:
`101284_2012110634 Sachine 130 AB i HeisMakeBoravia (Olive )`
`202373_2012110640 Snowchine 7 AB i Flanders`
`300738_2012110658_Machine VP 7 AB i Renamed v 500185`

I'm writing a script to parse dirs and get some data (serial, name, comments) from dir names as well as enumerate some files in particular (always same) subdir of dirs in list. I generated a list of dirs by `ls > results.txt` I run script by `parse.sh results.txt`

I completed the first half of the script which gets the data I need from the names of dirs (omited some of lines as they are not relevant) and it works. I have the problem with 2nd part of the script which firs looks if subdir exist and then looks for files of type with file and gets their name and their md5 hash. The 2nd part works on it's own if run in dir with no spaces on it's own.

```
#!/bin/bash
# manually set working directory /sample or /rlisti must combine with parse.sh sample.txt or results.txt
WORKING_DIR='/sample'

# read from input file which is generated from ls dir > results.txt
# usage ./parse.sh results.txt

while IFS= read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do

  # some tests which find variables from $line

  MACHINE_SN=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/')
  BOARD_SN=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*[ _]*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/')

  if echo $line | grep -iqF air
  then
    AIR='1'
  else
    AIR='0'
  fi

  # tests to find and hash particular files in sub dirs
  # test if there is directory Actual_Program_and_Database in current line.

  if [ -d "$WORKING_DIR"/"$line"/Actual_Program_and_Database ]
  then

    # if dir exists set SW_DIR to 'Actual_Program_and_Database

    SW_DIR='Actual_Program_and_Database'

    # count files in dir, there should be 3 or 4, good to know if there are less or more as those are exceptions

    NUM_FILES=$(ls "$WORKING_DIR"/"$line"/Actual_Program_and_Database | wc -l)
    DB_COUNTER=1 # count Clarion DB files in dir

    # test each file - this works on it's own when run in same directory with files
    # but fails if lines contain spaces

    for FILENAME in "$WORKING_DIR"/"$line"/Actual_Program_and_Database/*
    do

      # bellow works when script is run from same directory
      # FILENAME is just file without it's leading path - so I'm trying to merge it with line

      FILENAME_PATH="$WORKING_DIR"/"$line"/Actual_Program_and_Database/"$FILENAME"

      # files of type Clarion are DB, there is DB1 and DB2 if there is also DB3 that is exception

      if file "$FILENAME" | grep -q Clarion
      then

        # Create variables with name DB_PATH1 DB_PATH2 etc
        # eval works on it's own but breaks if paths contain spaces or ()&

        eval 'DB_PATH'$DB_COUNTER="$FILENAME_PATH" # path to filename for use with md5sum
        eval 'DB_NAME'$DB_COUNTER=$(basename "$FILENAME_PATH") # name of DBx file
        eval 'DB_HASH'$DB_COUNTER=$(md5sum "$FILENAME_PATH" | awk '{ print $1 }') # create hash  of DBx
        ((DB_COUNTER ++)) # increase DB counter

      # files of type POSIX are SCRIPTs there should be only one

      elif file "$FILENAME" | grep -q POSIX
      then
        SCRIPT_PATH=$FILENAME_PATH
        SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename $FILENAME_PATH)
        SCRIPT_HASH=$(md5sum $FILENAME_PATH | awk '{ print $1 }')

      # files of type CRLF are LISTs there should be only one

      elif file "$FILENAME" | grep -q CRLF
      then
        LIST_PATH=$FILENAME_PATH
        LIST_NAME=$(basename $FILENAME_PATH)
        LIST_HASH=$(md5sum $FILENAME_PATH | awk '{ print $1 }')
      else
        UNKNOWN_FILE='1'
      fi
    done

  # if there isn't directory Actual_Program_and_Database in current line set dir to 0
  # there are not enough exceptions to program for them

  else
    SW_DIR='0'
  fi

  # Print results (for now - will write SQL statements to populate database once script works)

  echo 'serial='$SERIAL
  echo 'machine sn =   '$MACHINE_SN # Valmar machine SN
  echo 'board sn =     '$BOARD_SN # electronic board SN
  echo 'NUM_FILES =    '$NUM_FILES # number of files in directory
  echo 'NUM_DBS =      '$NUM_DBS # number of files in directory - not working
  echo 'DB_COUNTER=  '$DB_COUNTER
  echo 'SCRIPT_NAME= '$SCRIPT_NAME
  echo 'SCRIPT_HASH= '$SCRIPT_HASH
  echo 'LIST_NAME=   '$LIST_NAME
  echo 'LIST_HASH=   '$LIST_HASH
  echo 'DB_NAME1=    '$DB_NAME1
  echo 'DB_HASH1=    '$DB_HASH1
  echo 'DB_NAME2=    '$DB_NAME2
  echo 'DB_HASH2=    '$DB_HASH2
  echo 'UNKNOWN_FILE='$UNKNOWN_FILE

  # added sleep so I can stop script when it fails to see results

  sleep 10

done < "$1"
```

Should I add sed to beginning to create LINE_ESCAPED which would escape all spaces brackets in lines and use that in 2nd part? or is should I rewrite the script to work on share instead of results.txt and would this even work?

Comment: Your `for FILENAME in` is populating `$FILENAME` with a full path. When you append that, you're then doubling it up.

Comment: Beyond that, see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). `eval` is unsafe to use, and you don't need it -- you can perform indirect assignments without its use.

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, fix the bugs it finds (many of them quoting related), and try to build a [mcve] that with the *shortest possible code* that generates a specific problem.

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables that are meaningful to the shell itself, whereas lowercase names are guaranteed not to modify shell behavior unintentionally; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, for the pertinent convention.

Comment: (Also, it's orders-of-magnitude faster to run `if [[ $foo = *POSIX* ]]` than `echo "$foo" | grep -q POSIX`, as the former is using only functionality built into the shell; consider capturing `file` output only once, and testing it multiple times -- a `case` statement might be a sane way to do that too).

Answer (score 0):

I had some mistakes with quote and I was appending path. I used eval before because I needed db1= db2= and I wanted to use eval to generate variable numbers. I switched to array[counter] from eval as I avoid eval and array does what I need. Didn't know about arrays - this is my first more serious bash script.

I also fixed all caps variables and used suggestion to test file $filename only once. Here is my code that now works. Thank everyone for suggestions.

```
if [ -d "$working_dir"/"$line"/Actual_Program_and_Database ]
then
  sw_dir='Actual_Program_and_Database'
  num_files=$(ls "$working_dir"/"$line"/Actual_Program_and_Database | wc -l) #count files in dir
  db_counter=0 # count Clarion DB files in dir
  for filename in "$working_dir"/"$line"/Actual_Program_and_Database/*
  do
  file_type=$(file "$filename")
  if [[ $file_type = *Clarion* ]]
    then
      db_path[$db_counter]=$filename
      db_name[$db_counter]=$(basename "$filename")
      db_hash[$db_counter]=$(md5sum "$filename" | awk '{ print $1 }')
      ((db_counter ++))
     elif [[ $file_type = *POSIX* ]]
     then
       script_path=$filename
       script_name=$(basename "$filename")
       script_hash=$(md5sum "$filename" | awk '{ print $1 }')
     elif [[ $file_type = *CRLF* ]]
     then
       list_path=$filename
       list_name=$(basename "$filename")
       list_hash=$(md5sum "$filename" | awk '{ print $1 }')
     else
       unknown_file='1'
  fi
  done
else
  sw_dir='0'
fi
```